# RootFrame UriMapper for Caliburn Micro

Tags: windows-phone-8, oauth-2.0, caliburn.micro

I have been googling on how to actually implement this with no avail. Could not find a single resource on how to actually do it using Caliburn Micro.

Basically, I am trying this http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/OAuth_on_Windows_Phone

In the example, it used `redirect_uri` as normal link. I did it with Protocol/File Association (refer http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/URI_associations_for_Windows_Phone_8). Everything works fine. I got it to work without Caliburn Micro.

But based on that example, I would require to implement `UriMapperBase` and assigned it to `RootFrame.UriMapper`.

My question is how do I actually implement `UriMapper` with CaliburnMicro for WP8. For Win 8, it is different as I could override the `OnActivate` and check for the `ActivationKind.Protocol` and there is no need for `UriMapper`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Finally managed to get it to work. So, will post it here because I'm pretty sure there will be a lost soul again like me who will appreciate the answer to this.

To use `UriMapper` in Caliburn, you will need to override the `CreatePhoneApplicationFrame` in the `bootsrapper`.

In `Boostrapper.cs`

```
protected override PhoneApplicationFrame CreatePhoneApplicationFrame()
{
    // var frame = base.CreatePhoneApplicationFrame(); this doesnt work
    var frame = new PhoneApplicationFrame(); // this works
    frame.UriMapper = new AssociationUriMapper();

    return frame;
}
```

`AssociationUriMapper.cs` - I just followed the example as per links above

```
public class AssociationUriMapper : UriMapperBase
{
    private string tempUri;


    public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
    {
        tempUri = System.Net.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.ToString());

        // URI association launch for contoso.
        if (tempUri.Contains("pocketthis:MainPage"))
        {
            // Get the category ID (after "CategoryID=").
            //int categoryIdIndex = tempUri.IndexOf("CategoryID=") + 11;
            //string categoryId = tempUri.Substring(categoryIdIndex);

            // Views/MainPage.xaml returns external exception, 
            // so remember the / before views
            return new Uri("/Views/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        }

        // Otherwise perform normal launch.
        return uri;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help anyone trying to implement Uri/File Association in WP8 with Caliburn Micro.

Comment: Say you return an Uri like "/Views/MainPage.xaml?param=x", ow to you get the param in the ViewModel?

Comment: If I not mistaken, that should do it.